# Class based view Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

how convert this code to class based code

```
def detail_article(request, slug):

context = {
    "article": get_object_or_404(Articles, slug=slug, state="p")
    "slider" : Articles.objects.filter(state="p").order_by('-publish')[:20]
}
return render(request, "blogApp/detail_article.html", context)
```

I tried this :

```
class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
context_object_name = 'slider'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Articles.objects.filter(state="p").order_by('-publish')[:6]

def get_object(self):
    slug = self.kwargs.get("slug")
    return get_object_or_404(Articles, slug=slug, state="p")
```

but I got this error : 'Articles' object is not iterable

and also i have for loop in my template on slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line.

```
context_object_name = 'slider'
```

Your template is expecting an object named slider. You should probably name the object context and then have a method like so.

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    slug = self.kwargs.get("slug")
    context["articles"] = get_object_or_404(Articles, slug=slug, state="p")        
    return context
```

You dont need `get_queryset` because a queryset is used for a `ListView`. A `DetailView` shows data on just one model instance. Which is what you want.